# property update does not exist on type AngularFirestoreCollection<any>

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I try to do this but get error:

```
checkOrUnCheckTitle($key: string , flag: boolean) {
    this.toDoList.update($key, { isChecked: flag})  ;
```

> property update does not exist on type AngularFirestoreCollection<any>

What's going wrong?

Comment: I am using Firestore

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack Overflow please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask your question. Best is to provide your code for better understanding of the context and also error log